# What causes the striations in this slope map?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, cartography, arcgis-10.4, slope, watershed

I have created this slope map using a 10m DEM from alabamaview.org and I just noticed it has small striations (zoom to see):

[image] 
What could cause this, and is it a big deal, or am I over-analyzing the map?

Comment: could it be something [like this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/107477/55203), artefacts from nearest-neighbour interpolation?

Comment: Possibly, but I didn't resample the DEM (unless running a slope analysis is resampling?), so I'm thinking it could be a legacy issue.